# Rails, getting each routes "parts" array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to output the "parts" for each route in my application, I have some code like this:

```
route = Rails.application.routes.routes.first
puts route.path.build_formatter
```

I see the output:

```
=> #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Format:0x007ff2c8f0c748
 @children=[6],
 @parameters=[],
 @parts=
  ["/",
   "rails",
   "/",
   "info",
   "/",
   "properties",
   #<ActionDispatch::Journey::Format:0x007ff2c8f0c928
    @children=[],
    @parameters=[1],
    @parts=
     [".",
      #<struct ActionDispatch::Journey::Format::Parameter
       name=:format,
       escaper=
        #<Proc:0x007ff2c1c02c70@/Users/{..}/lib/action_dispatch/journey/visitors.rb:6 (lambda)>>]>]>
```

In the output I see this array:

```
["/",
 "rails",
 "/",
 "info",
 "/",
 "properties",
```

How can I get that array for each route in my application? It's easy for me to get it as a string, and then split it all back out, but I would like to know how to get this more directly from Rails, any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
instance_variable_get("@parts")
```